# Demeaning / Mean-centering in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I looked for an answer but wasn't able to find one, so I hope this is a topic, which hasn't been touched upon yet.

I have a xlsx panel data file from CRSP for monthly stock returns for all companies in the NYSE from 1963 until 2017. Those are the columns:

Month (in DD/MM/YYYY) | Company Code | Company Name | Industry Code | Return

e.g. 31/03/1981       | AAPL         | Apple Inc.   | 12345         | -0.07512

Now I want to calculate the demeaning returns in an extra column, i.e. Return(Apple,March1981) MINUS Mean-Return(Apple,whole sample period).
I was trying with the scale function, but obviously, it demeans the return for the mean of all returns, not only apple specific. How do I code that it should only take the apple returns into the mean calucations?

Thank you in advance and have a good day!

EDIT: removed the excel file.

Comment: Without reproducible data this is hard to verify, but you probably want this from `dplyr`:  `df %>% group_by(\`Company Code\`) %>% mutate(demeaned = Return - mean(Return))`

Comment: It doesn't work I think because there are also non-numeric values in the column, sometimes there are blanks or letters like "A" or "B" in the column.  
I tried it with:
    `dplyr::select_if(Returns, is.numeric)`    
and  
    `nums <- as.numeric(levels(Returns))[as.integer(Returns)]    
    m <- mean(nums, na.rm = T)    
    nums[is.na(nums)] <- m    
    Returns_new.x <- nums`  

But it did not work.

Comment: `as.numeric` can't magically make things into numeric values, especially for blanks or letters. you need to remove those rows, with `filter` or another method.

Comment: I have this now:
``` r
testdata1 %>% 
  group_by(`Ticker Symbol`) %>%
  mutate(`Return adj.` = as.numeric(`Return adj.`)) %>%
  mutate(avg_return = mean(`Return adj.`, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(demeaned_return = `Return adj.` - avg_return)
#> Error in testdata1 %>% group_by(`Ticker Symbol`) %>% mutate(`Return adj.` = as.numeric(`Return adj.`)) %>% : konnte Funktion "%>%" nicht finden
```

Somehow it says that it cannot find the function "%>%" although I have installed dplyr. And there is no new column, so the mutate function didn't go through.

Comment: Have you called `library(dplyr)` after installing it? and you didn't assign the result of the pipe back to any object; start it with `x <- testdata %>% ...`

Comment: Thank you so much, I think that did the trick for me!!! Have a great day!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answering my question myself, before you have to read the whole comment section:

As @Calum You mentioned, I simply forgot to assign the new pipe back to an object. The code I used is:

```
maindata <- testdata1 %>%
group_by(Ticker Symbol) %>%
mutate(Return = as.numeric(Return)) %>%
mutate(avg_return = mean(Return, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
mutate(demeaned_return = Return - avg_return)
```

Best,
Kleinad